# gnome-terminal not working after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: python, 17.10, gnome-terminal

I have some problems with my ubuntu after I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10

gnome-terminal isn't working. I tried to fix it for few hours without any success.

When I'm running gnome-terminal from xterm(that does work) I get a python syntax error due to the line "print url" - what suggests that it is a python2 script. So I changed /usr/bin/gnome-terminal file to run with python instead of python3.

Then I got some problems related to gi package. I searched for solutions and tried after reinstall gi, but then I got this error:

from gi-repository import GLib, Gio
importError: no module named repository

I found out that gnome-terminal.real works. But I've no idea how to fix this python problem. Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` wrapper script shipped by Ubuntu 17.10's gnome-terminal package. It contains no `print url` – in fact, contains neither the word `print` nor `url`. You probably modified this script or installed an unofficial version.

Please reinstall `gnome-terminal` and `gnome-terminal-data` from the official Ubuntu repositories. Also make sure that all the package dependencies are satisfied, the gi-repository imports should succeed then.

Comment: The error message, when I use python3.6, is:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
       print url

Comment: your answer encourages me to check again more deeply the error message.  I found out it's about gi package in python3.6. After a short google search, I found I need to uninstall gi package and it solved the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If installing an additional package breaks gnome-terminal then this is something you should file into Ubuntu's bugtracker and  its developers should investigate.